# I can't ssh in from outside my network, but I can from inside

Tags: ssh, connection

My ssh server is set up on the standard port, and I forwarded the correct port in my router, but I'm still getting a "connection refused" message when trying to connect from the outside. I can connect from the inside just fine.

Comment: If you can connect to the SSH server from the local network but not from the general internet the issue lies not with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect from your local network, Ubuntu most likely has nothing to do with it - it's a network configuration issue.

Many ISPs block incoming connections on "unusual" ports (or all incoming connections). Some ISPs have a setting in their control panel enabling/disabling port blocking.

As a diagnostic - try exposing port 80 (Apache running some webpage) - I'm almost sure you'll find it doesn't work either.

You can also fiddle with modem settings (how do you know you forwarded "the correct port"?), but this would only help after you triple-checked your provider doesn't block you.

Comment: +1 also just to add that the [M-Lab](http://www.measurementlab.net/measurement-lab-tools) set of tools are quite comprehensive, and can sometimes help with more obscure connection problems.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, add another non standard listening port (say 2222) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, then do `sudo service ssh restart` and forward this port in your router too. Then try to ssh from outside with option `-p2222`.